# Polymorphism and Overriding in Python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

I have two classes: A and B. I would like to build a class C which is able to overrides some common methods of A and B. 
The methods which I would like to override they should be able to call the method of the base class.

In practice I would like to collect some statistics about class A and B, but being transparent to the rest of my code. Now, A and B have some methods in common (obviously implemented in a different way). I would like to have a class C which shares the interface of A and B, and simoultaneously do some other operations (i.e. measure the run time of some shared methods).

I can make this example:

```
import time
class A:

     def __init__(self):
          pass

     def common_method(self):
          return "A"

class B:

     def __init__(self):
          pass

     def common_method(self):
          return "B"

class C:

     def __init__(self, my_obj):
          self.my_obj
          self.time_avg = 0
          self.alpha = 0.1
          pass

     def common_method(self):
          start = time.time()
          ret =  self.my_obj.common_method()
          stop = time.time()
          self.time_avg = (1. - self.alpha) * self.time_avg + self.alpha * (stop - start)
          return ret
```

I hope that from this example is clear that A and B inheriting from C is *not* working.

However, this method unfortunately require me to redefine all the methods of classes A and B... Which is tedious and dirty!

What is the proper way to implement this situation in python? And how it is called the design pattern (I am almost sure that there is but I cannot recall).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In order to override a method of e. g. A your class C must inherit A: class C(A). An redefinition is necessary, if you want a behavior different from the one of the base class.

Comment: So is class `C` supposed to override methods of class `A` or class `B`? I don't understand your problem. It would probably help if you explained your use case for this code. This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Humbalan Yes, sure. But How can I do it by conditioning on two different classes? I wrote the example with a boxing technique to make clear my problem, but I wish to use inheritance.

Comment: Right, so why doesn't simple composition work? What methods do you have to re-write? I don't understand why you have to redefine all the methods of classes A and B.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga class A and B have more methods. I have to rewrite in class C, for every of this methods something like def other_method(*args, **kwargs): return self.my_obj.other_method(*args, **kwargs). It is still doable, but I think there should be a nicer solution. Maybe I am wrong about that

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with composition instead of polymorphism, meaning that a C object will hold either a A object or a B one:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._obj = obj
    def common_method(self):
        return self._obj.common_method()
```

You can then use it:

```
>>> ca = C(A())
>>> cb = C(B())
>>> ca.common_method()
'A'
>>> cb.common_method()
'B'
```

Beware: if you pass an object that does not declare a `common_method` method, you will get an `AttributeError`

Comment: Not at the time I answered.

Comment: Are you sure? However this way has the problem that I have to re-declare every other method of A and B in C. You have to imagine that I have a lot of code running object of kind A and B, and I want just use a class C to "augment" A and B, but still this operation must be transparent to the rest of the code. And here, something similar to the inheritance would be really appropriate, instead of this "boxing". If there is no other way in python, then I'll implement in this way, but honestly I consider it a dirty solution.